# understanding jquery getjson approach

Tags: php, jquery, json

In an earlier post today the answer has led me down the route of using a JSON feed to populate elements in my page.

Something new to learn!!

the JSON data is created from a PHP script which retrieves the data from a Mysql database. The php script retrieves a specific record which I need to pass to the php script with the getJson call.

I've had success with creating the url with the parameters added as a GET method but I can't find an example of a POST method - the parameters should go as an optional parameter. here's what I have so far...

```
function loadData(index) {
        alert(index);//debug
            $.getJSON('loadJSONholeData.php' , 
                {hole: index} ,
                function(data) {
```

I've found examples for a twitter feed which shows a parameter like option: "cat", but can't find an option where the value is in a variable.

I don't understand how to use the parameters - where am I going wrong. Appreciate this is probably a fundamental issue but I'm learning.

Thanks

Update:
I've revised the code per the responses below and used both suggestions to pass the POST parameter, but the receiving PHP code is not reading the POST parameter and just returns the default query values.

I even used as static value of 1 both as a value and as a string but no joy.

Here's my receiving PHP code which accesses the POST values:

```
$hole = 3;
if (isset($_POST['hole'])) {
$hole = $_POST['hole'];
}
```

I'm missing something basic here. The value in 'index' definitely exists as it shows in the debug and JSON data is being returned )(but the default). I can go back to my GET method but want to see this work!!

Thanks

Update: Success!!

I played around further with the revised code. I removed the content type parameter from the code and it all works now, the PHP is returning the correct query.

I assume then that by specifying the JSON type in contentType it passes the POST parameter in a different way to PHP which expects it in anpther way?

Onwards and upwards - thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $.getJSON() method does an HTTP GET and not POST. Try something like this -

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'loadJSONholeData.php',
            data: JSON.stringify({hole: index }),          
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
            //(result.d) has your data.
            }
        });
```

Comment: I added an update, tried this approach but POST parameters dont seem to be being passed

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP code (I'm into C#) but it looks like you're trying to access the values from the form's post values. The values are not in there. Your server-side method should have a parameter by the same name `hole`, then access the value from the parameter. Makes sense? Equivalent code in C# is `public static void loadJSONholeData(string hole) { //hole has the value of index. }`

Comment: Sort of - I have though just managed to get it to work - I've updated my post with what I did - thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Each key/value pair in the arguments object will represent a parameter in the HTTP POST. You can use variables as values, but I believe they will be converted to strings, so it's better to do the conversion yourself (so you can make sure they have the correct format). A simple example:

```
var dynamicValue = foo();
$.post('my/url', { var1:"static value", var2:dynamicValue }, function(data) {
   // Your callback; the format of "data" will depend on the 4th parameter to post...
}, "json"); // ...in this case, json
```

Now, in case your server is expecting a json encoded object/list, you can pass it by using `JSON.stringify`:

```
function foo() {
    return JSON.stringify({ my:"object" });
}
```

`JSON` should be available in most modern browsers, in case it's not, you can get it [here](http://www.json.org/) (json2.js, under "JavaScript").